# Extend or Append for String in method

Tags: python, python-2.7, append, extend

I have files with words and i want to add them together and with the condition of unique words only. How to implement that?
Here is the example :

```
words1 = {'view', 'lower', 'sample','good'}
words2 = {'sold', 'good', 'part', 'view'}
```

The answer should be :

```
words = {'view', 'lower', 'sample', 'good', 'sold', 'part'}
```

Comment: You listed `'view'` twice in the output..

Comment: Sorry, I did changes to it. Actually I'm getting error of  AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'union' in the program. What should I do?

Comment: Then you don't have sets; your code *posted here* uses sets, but your actual code has lists instead. Turn your lists into sets by calling `set()` on them first.

Comment: words = `set(words1).union(words2)` would do.

Comment: How do i need to implement it for dictionary defined as dict = {} and I have to add all words to it from different sets?

Comment: What would be the keys and what would be the values?

Comment: I have defined wdict as a dictionary and i have to add all unique words from different files which are sorted as a list.

Comment: No idea what that looks like; you didn't tell me anything about what the keys are, for example.

Comment: I am unable to add program here. Should i edit the question?

Comment: That'd would be a *new* question.

Comment: I have added the question if u want to try.

Comment: No, I meant you should make that a new post :-) don't alter this question; it is answered and done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have sets, and you want the union:

```
words = words1 | words2
```

where the [Python `set` type](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) has overloaded the [`|` operator to return the union](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.union) of two sets.

You can also use the explicit `set.union()` method:

```
words = words1.union(words2)
```

Demo:

```
>>> words1 = {'view', 'lower', 'sample','good'}
>>> words2 = {'sold', 'good', 'part', 'view'}
>>> words1 | words2
{'lower', 'good', 'sold', 'part', 'sample', 'view'}
>>> words1.union(words2)
{'lower', 'good', 'sold', 'part', 'sample', 'view'}
```

`'view'` and `'good'` are present in both input sets, so the output is a set of 6 unique words.